# Sequencing and Evaluating Duplicates in a vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a variable that identifies if a string within a vector is the first appearance, in the top three, or more than three. For example:

In the data set below, I have name (there will be more names), text, and a dup variable. I want the dup variable to identify if the text is appearing for the first time (origin), if it's within the first three occurrences (FirstThree) or if it has appeared more than the three times(MoreThanThree). I will also need to do that for each person... but I think I can figure that part out. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
name =c("T","T","T","T","T","T","T","T","T","T")
text =c("a","b","a","a","b","c","a","a","b","a")
dup =c("origin","origin","FirstThree","FirstThree","FirstThree","origin","MoreThanThree","MoreThanThree","FirstThree","MoreThanThree")
dfA = data.frame(name,text,dup)

 name text           dup
1     T    a        origin
2     T    b        origin
3     T    a    FirstThree
4     T    a    FirstThree
5     T    b    FirstThree
6     T    c        origin
7     T    a MoreThenThree
8     T    a MoreThenThree
9     T    b    FirstThree
10    T    a MoreThenThree
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data.table::rowid` with two `ifelse` checks

```
dfA[, ict := {
        r <- rowid(text)
        ifelse(r == 1, 'origin', 
        ifelse(r <= 3, 'FirstThree', 
               'MoreThanThree'))}
    , by = name]

dfA
#     name text           dup           ict
#  1:    T    a        origin        origin
#  2:    T    b        origin        origin
#  3:    T    a    FirstThree    FirstThree
#  4:    T    a    FirstThree    FirstThree
#  5:    T    b    FirstThree    FirstThree
#  6:    T    c        origin        origin
#  7:    T    a MoreThanThree MoreThanThree
#  8:    T    a MoreThanThree MoreThanThree
#  9:    T    b    FirstThree    FirstThree
# 10:    T    a MoreThanThree MoreThanThree
```

You could also use `cut`. Only difference is this produces a factor rather than character. May be useful if you have more than 3 categories

```
dfA[, ict := cut(rowid(text), c(0, 1, 3, Inf), 
                 labels = c('origin', 'FirstThree', 'MoreThanThree'))
    , by = name]
```

Comment: Nice ! I didn't know rowid and would still have used `seq_len(.N)` along with `by=.(name, text)` for that purpose

Comment: Or using `base R` `with(dfA, cut(ave(seq_along(text), text, name, FUN = seq_along), c(0, 1, 3, Inf), labels = c('origin', 'FirstThree', 'MoreThanThree')))`

Comment: didn't know the use of `ave`. I had the same kind of solution using `data.table` :
`dt[, dup_cut := cut(x = 1:.N, breaks = c(0, 1, 3, Inf), 
                    include.lowest = T, labels = c("origin", "FirstThree", "MoreThanThree")), by = .(name, text)]`

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr`, we can compare the `row_number()` in a `case_when` statement.

```
library(dplyr)

dfA %>%
  group_by(text) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
         dup = case_when(row == 1 ~ "origin", 
                         row <= 3 ~ "FirstThree", 
                         TRUE ~ "MoreThenThree"))

#   name  text    row dup          
#   <fct> <fct> <int> <chr>        
# 1 T     a         1 origin       
# 2 T     b         1 origin       
# 3 T     a         2 FirstThree   
# 4 T     a         3 FirstThree   
# 5 T     b         2 FirstThree   
# 6 T     c         1 origin       
# 7 T     a         4 MoreThenThree
# 8 T     a         5 MoreThenThree
# 9 T     b         3 FirstThree   
#10 T     a         6 MoreThenThree
```

We can remove the `row` column later if not needed.